# Python - ImportError: No module named

Tags: python-2.7

I have following directory structure:

```
img_search
   --- server
       --- __init__.py
       --- server_flask.py
   --- tests
       --- __init__.py
       --- test_kdtree.py
       --- test_distance_matrix.py
   --- __init__.py
   --- kdtree.py
   --- distance_matrix.py
```

*__init__.py* in server and tests are empty and *__init__.py* in img_search contains following code:

```
from img_search import distance_matrix, kdtree
```

I use class from *kdtree* in *server_flask.py* using following import:

```
from img_search import kdtree
```

When I run *server_flask.py* in PyCharm it works without any problems, however when I run it in terminal, I get an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   `File "server_flask.py", line 2, in <module>`
>
> `from img_search import kdtree`
>
> `ImportError: No module named img_search`

How can I fix this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really need this, another option will be to mess with `path`. In your `server_flask.py` add following lines:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))
```

`sys.path.append` will add to a path a module location which will be found by `join`ing `dirname` of `server_flask.py` `__file__` and its `../..` directory. Here we are.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have some meaningful reason to do it that way but it doesn't need to look like this.

In general, modules should provide some functionalities and be consistent as one package or library that is providing some API.

In other words this should be avoided:

```
python server_flask.py
```

or

```
python img_search/server/server_flask.py
```

But this one is totally fine:

```
python main.py
```

With `main.py` having some kind of:

```
from img_search.server import server_flask
# Do something if needed
```

Have a good one!